# How to configure the Fields plugin to filter the domain

Tags: grails

I have an Author who has a Book.

```
class Author {
   String name
   Book book
}
```

The `<f:all bean="Author"/>` tag in the edit.gsp will create a html textbox with the Author.name and a html dropdown box with **all** the books in the html  element.

How to setup the Fields plugin to only show just a sub-set of the books (not all the books)?

Comment: "How to setup the Fields plugin to only show just a sub-set of the books " -  Which subset would you like to show?

Comment: Let for example,  the author signed up with the publisher Penguin.  So, I want the Fields plugin to fill out the book dropdown with all the books that are published by Penguin only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(from the question...)

> How to setup the Fields plugin to only show just a sub-set of the
> books (not all the books)?

(from a comment...)

> So, I want the Fields plugin to fill out the book dropdown with all
> the books that are published by Penguin only.

The fields plugin does not provide a mechanism to do that filtering.

Comment: If the Fields plugin does not provide a mechanism to do this particular filtering, what other mechanism does the Fields plugin provide to filter any row?

Comment: " what other mechanism does the Fields plugin provide to filter any row?" - Filtering the data before you get to the view layer is a common approach.  You could also have a custom tag which iterates over the collection and only renders the ones that satisfy some criteria.

Comment: Got it!  So, No Answer is the answer.  Thx!

Comment: "So, No Answer is the answer." - I am not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: This is one of the quotes printed in one of my Software Engineering books.  **There ain't no answer. There ain't gonna be any answer. There never has been an answer. That's the answer.**  You never heard of this?

Comment: "You never heard of this?" - Right.  I had not heard of this.  That is why I asked.  I don't agree that there isn't an answer.  It is my understanding that the fields plugin does not support what you are asking.  I can show you an example app that shows how to accomplish what you want without the fields plugin if you can describe a minimal data set that would represent the requirement.

Comment: I have attempted to delete the answer but SO won't let me because it has been accepted.

Comment: I will need to ask in another question if you want detail. I have a class that has 20+ properties.  I don't want to roll my own edit.gsp.  Too much typing. <f:all> looks good enough to me.  I have so far 3 dropdown boxes. I need to change the content of these dropdown boxes based on the contents in the other properties of the class.  I am doing the lookup in the client-side. This means massive amount of JQuery using a bunch of Map generated and converted from Groovy to Javascript sent to the view.

Comment: See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/tom6502books. 3 books are created at https://github.com/jeffbrown/tom6502books/blob/main/grails-app/init/tom6502books/BootStrap.groovy#L6-L8 but only 2 show up in the dropdown at http://localhost:8080/author/edit/1.

Comment: The ones in the list are put in the model at https://github.com/jeffbrown/tom6502books/blob/ecf7cc68777c4792ffc9496d4dcc154726f28b56/grails-app/controllers/tom6502books/AuthorController.groovy#L49 and rendered at https://github.com/jeffbrown/tom6502books/blob/ecf7cc68777c4792ffc9496d4dcc154726f28b56/grails-app/views/_fields/author/book/_widget.gsp#L1. No custom edit.gsp is required.

Comment: In that example, the filtering is being done in the database, not in the view rendering.

Comment: Ok thx.  I see.  So, there is no option for the plugin to filter the list but there is an option to set up the plugin to use another list.

Comment: "So, there is no option for the plugin to filter the list but there is an option to set up the plugin to use another list." - I think both of those are true.  The fields plugin only works if you give it data, and you get to decide what data to give it.  In this example, the fields plugin is not responsible for any filtering.

Comment: I am sorry there has been confusion.  I thought you wanted to know if the fields plugin could do the kind of filtering you want to do, and I believe the answer is "no".  GORM can do all kinds of filtering, almost any filtering supported by whatever kind of database you are using.

Comment: There are details missing that would help define the best solution (for example, when the Books are being filtered, how the app decides which records to select) so the thing above may not be the best solution.  Another option is a custom tag.  There are a lot of options, but I think asking Fields to do the work probably isn't one of them.  Best of luck!

Comment: Ten-4.  Thanks!  I think I will send the Fields an empty list and then build the <option> from a ajax call to get the list I want.  I don't want to keep hitting the database repeatedly.  But I see no other option.

Comment: "and then build the <option> from a ajax call to get the list" - The endpoint that the ajax call invokes can render ta GSP template and return the result of that in the response.  That is a common technique.